# Confusion about the "leading edge" and "trailing edge" and "clock cycle" terms in SPI

Tags: signal, spi, clock

This question refers to the [Wikipedia page of SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface), to the section about Clock Polarity and Phase. I've read what's written there and got pretty confused about these terms. My question is:

Is "clock cycle" defined as the period of time that the data line is at a certain state (HIGH or LOW)? Or is it defined as a cycle of "leading edge" followed by a "trailing edge"? From the diagram is seems that the former is the correct option but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

Cycle of clock means same as cycle for sine wave, i.e. from rising edge to next rising edge, or from falling edge to falling edge etc.

Answer (score 1):

If CPOL—Clock idle POLarity— is low, then rising edge is used.  The opposite may also be used if agreed at each end.

Correct, the term "cycle" just means the repeating **active time period**  of both positive and negative duration *in any order*.  ( ignore idle time )

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?